# Skype Android use headset but record sound from phone's microphone

Tags: skype, microphone, headset

**Environment**: Skype on Android 4.1

**Hardware**: Galaxy S2 + earplugs without microphone

Is it possible to use phone's built-in microphone while using earplugs during a skype call?